# Почему не выводятся данные из таблицы mysql в java (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, запрос, jdbc, mysql-workbench

1) Хочу вывести данные из базы mybase(MySQL),таблицы new_table.

Их атрибуты : int id, VARCHAR(45) word, int tonality

Данные для подключения: user root, password 1234

Программа выводит данные об успешном подключении к БД и завершении, но не сами данные почему так?

2) Как проверить что слово, которое ввёл пользователь(например с помощью метода scanner), есть в БД(таблица new_table, столбец word) ?

package com.jdbc;

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    //static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mybase";
    static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybase";

    //  Database credentials

    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "1234";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM new_table";
            ResultSet new_table = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while(new_table.next()){
                //Retrieve by column name
                int id  = new_table.getInt("id");
                int tonality = new_table.getInt("tonality");
                String word = new_table.getString("word");


                //Display values
                System.out.print("id: " + id);
                System.out.print(",word: " + word);
                System.out.print(",tonality: " + tonality);

            }
            new_table.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
            }// do nothing
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

***java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException***

У вас синтаксическая ошибка в запросе sql

```
String sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM new_table";
```

Comment: исправила, но данные все-равно не выводятся